# Color in a box, c# Console Application

Tags: c#

I am creating a Bordered Box that should create a box with different colors at the border. this is my code:

```
class BorderedBox : ColoredBox
{
    public int heigth;
    public int width;

    ConsoleColor color = borderColor;

    public BorderedBox (Point p, int width, int height, ConsoleColor backColor, ConsoleColor borderColor)
        : base (p, width, height, backColor)
    {
            this.borderColor = borderColor;
    }
    public override void Draw()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(p.X, p.Y + j);

            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {   
                if (i == 0 || i == width - 1 || j == 0 || j == height - 1)
                Console.BackgroundColor = borderColor;

                else 

                Console.BackgroundColor = backColor;

                Console.Write(' ');





            }
        }
    }
}
```

However im geting errors at the [ ConsoleColor color = borderColor; ] , it says that "the name ' borderColor ' does not exist in the current context. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see `borderColor` defined anywhere.

Comment: There is no `backColor` either.

Answer (score 5):

At the point you try to assign `ConsoleColor color = borderColor`, `borderColor` has not been defined. I suspect you have just messed up your variable declaration and really meant:

```
ConsoleColor borderColor;
```

Instead of:

```
ConsoleColor color = borderColor;
```